# How to use semantic-ui with cdn?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I have added the cdn of semantic ui in my html file but now I want to write react code using semantic ui in my js file. How to use semantic-ui in the js file?

I have used material-ui where we use MaterialUi keyword to get the components.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Transaction Entry</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'images/icons/favicon.ico' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
        input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
        input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
        input[type=date]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
          -webkit-appearance: none;
          margin: 0;
        }
        input[type=number] {
            -moz-appearance:textfield;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #0747A6">
    <!-- DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING DIV-->
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-autosuggest/dist/standalone/autosuggest.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/node-uuid/1.4.8/uuid.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src={% static 'js/Signup.js' %}></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Html file

js/Signup.js will have my js code.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in semantic-ui-react docs, there is no CDN usage for `Components`, just only for `CSS`. (In playarround CDN is fine, but dont use it in prod.)
**resource:** https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage/